# Firestore get array from collection with id's to use in Polymer dom-repeat

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, polymer-2.x

im trying to use Firestore with Polymer, I obtain an array to send it to polymer in a dom-repeat like this:

```
    var query=db.collection("operaciones");
    db.collection("operaciones")              
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    });
        that.operacionesPorCliente=Array.from(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.data()));
    });
    console.log (that.operacionesPorCliente);   // this works but the ID doesnt exist here....
    }
```

that works but that array doesnt contain the id from firestore, the problem is that I need that ID to update the data :( but it isn't in the array

Hope I explain my self, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I make a Polymer Element (Polymer 3) to keep Firebase Firestore data synchronized. This component has a dom-repeat template element, to show the  always-fresh collection data.

I think this will answer your question

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import {} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.js';

/**
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
class FirebaseFirestoreApp extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
      <h1>Firestore test</h1>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[elems]]">
        <p>[[item.$id]] - [[item.name]]</p>
      </template>
    `;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      elems: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return [];
        }
      }
    };
  }

  ready() {
    super.ready();
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
    db.settings(settings);
    db.collection("operaciones").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          let newElem = this.makeElem(change);
          this.push('elems', newElem);
        }
        if (change.type === "modified") {
          let modifiedElement = this.makeElem(change);
          let index = this.getElemIndex(change.doc.id);
          this.set(`elems.${index}`, modifiedElement);
        }
        if (change.type === "removed") {
          let deletedElement = this.getElemIndex(change.doc.id);
          this.splice('elems', deletedElement, 1);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  makeElem(change) {
    let data = change.doc.data();
    data.$id = change.doc.id;
    return data;     
  }

  getElemIndex(id) {
    let index = this.elems.findIndex((elem) => {
      if(elem.$id == id) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return index;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('firebase-firestore-app', FirebaseFirestoreApp);
```

The sync systems should works with all kind of Firebase Firestore collections, but the template dom-repeat suposses there is a property called "name" in the objects inside the collection.

So, the collection in the Firebase console looks like that.

[Firebase console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYUpS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Polymerfire [Polymerfire](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire) that are polymer components for Firebase, but if you want to do it in javascript, can get the id directly in the doc: doc.id().

Comment: But the official Polymerfire doesnt have support yet for firestore, does it?

Comment: To work with storage you should first create a firebase reference, [firebase-storage-ref]( https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/elements/firebase-storage-ref),  with the path of the file and then download, upload or delete.